# C# Implement Interface and inheritance

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implment a property interface with a class inherit the declare one. Maybe the example is more easy to understand.

MyClassA is OK, but MyClassB has a compile error 'Test.MyClassB' does not implement interface member 'Test.IMyInterface.PropA'. 
Any Idea how I can do this?

/****** EDITED CODE ******/

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int PropA { get; set; }
}

public class InheritClass : BaseClass
{
    public int PropB { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
    BaseClass PropClass { get; set; }
}


public class MyClassA : IMyInterface
{

    public BaseClass PropClass { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassB : IMyInterface
{

    public InheritClass PropClass { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `MyClassB` *doesn't* implement `PropA`. What are you trying to do? You're not inheriting `MyClassB` from anything.

Comment: FYI - you can right click on the interface a class is inheriting from and 'Implement' any methods / properties the interface describes. (In visual studio, other IDE's may vary)

Comment: Okay, right, this is a lot clearer. You *must* use the exact same signature. Even though `InheritClass` inherits from `BaseClass`, the method signature still has to use `BaseClass`. The actual value may be `InheritClass`, but not the signature. Maybe you'd want to use a generic interface instead? Or a helper property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what you should do

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int PropA { get; set; }
}

public class InheritClass : BaseClass
{
    public int PropB { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
    BaseClass PropClass { get; set; }
}


public class MyClassA : IMyInterface
{

    public BaseClass PropClass { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassB : IMyInterface
{
    private BaseClass _propClass;

    public BaseClass PropClass
    {
        get { return (InheritClass)_propClass; }
        set { _propClass = (InheritClass)value; }
    }
}
```

this is not directly possible, also why you are trying to do this. if you have base class you can use its child to set or get...

Comment: this is correct. but i believe you are trying to achieve something that is not clear. the problem is somewhere else i guess @DiegoMartelli

Comment: Unfortunately it was clear, I only copy the wrong code. Thank you @M.kazem Akhgary.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface requires that all classes that implement it have the property `int PropA { get; set; }`, but your class `MyClassB` doesn't have this method yet is inheriting `IMyInterface`.

So you have two options.

One, just implement the interface:

```
public class MyClassB : IMyInterface
{
    public int PropA { get; set; }
    public int PropB { get; set; }
}
```

Or, two, if you wish to only expose `PropB` on `MyClassB` then you could explicitly implement the interface (and assuming that `PropB` should be the implementation) then you would do this:

```
public class MyClassB : IMyInterface
{
    int IMyInterface.PropA { get { return this.PropB; } set { this.PropB = value; } }
    public int PropB { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `PropA` in implements of MyClassB:

```
public class MyClassB : IMyInterface
{
**public int PropA { get; set; }**
public int PropB { get; set; }
}
```